# Alternating Visibilities of Views in Bottom of Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout and want to put a view (a AdMob view) on the bottom of the layout. This works fine, like so:

[image]

Now, if there is no internet connection, I want to replace the AdMob view with a placeholder ImageView. I want to do this by setting the AdMob view visibility to GONE and set the ImageView visibility to VISIBLE. But the result does not look right - the ImageView is now on top red and green parts, as shown below:

[image]

Here is the layout xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_above="@id/ad_view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#AA9999"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LEFT SIDE"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:text="some long text here"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#99AA99"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RIGHT SIDE" />

            <TextView
                android:text="MORE LONG TEXT HERE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ImageView
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/ad_placeholder"
        android:src="@drawable/ad_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to put both the ImageView and AdMob view in one linear layout (call this bottom linear layout), and have the main linear layout (@id/main) use a "layout_above" on the bottom linear layout. But the code won't compile.

Any suggestions?

Comment: give fix width to your imageview not wrap_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <!--Using relative layout to get the ad align property, could not get linear layout to work properly.-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adMob_container_my"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#AA9999"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LEFT SIDE"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some long text here"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#99AA99"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RIGHT SIDE"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MORE LONG TEXT HERE"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/adMob_container_my"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:adSize="BANNER">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ad_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pango_logo_title"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

you have forgotten the '+' sign in here:  `android:layout_above="@+id/adMob_container_my"`

Comment: Thanks, but when I compiled the code, I get this error message: Error:(17, 32) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adMob_container'). I am using Android Studio 1.4.1 targeting SDK 23 and min SDK 16.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out at the same time! Thanks. Answer accepted.